# How custom renderer?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, offline

I am working with Xamarin WebView and wanted to make my Xamarin app that will still load the Website when its offline.

Is there any Idea about Xamarin Webview load website when Offline?

I have been searching for this, I only see Java Android WebViews and nothing to see Xamarin forms

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/260307/#Comment_260307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use **Custom Renderer** to set the **CacheMode** on iOS and Android .

#### in Forms

Create a custom WebView

```
public class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Url",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

There is a `ReturnCacheDataElseLoad` Cache type of **NSUrlRequestCachePolicy** . You could set the value as **NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad** .

> Use existing cache data, regardless or age or expiration date, loading from originating source only if there is no cached data.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView),typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "Url")
            {
                NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url), NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, 5);
                Control.LoadRequest(request);               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### in Android

```
using Android.Content;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.Settings.CacheMode = Android.Webkit.CacheModes.CacheElseNetwork;
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to define it in xaml like following

```
<local:MyWebView Url="xxx" />
```

Comment: do you have A full Code of that man? i want to study your code then apply to my app if there is something improvements

Comment: I am new In Xamarin Forms Dont know yet about custom renderers

Comment: You could refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/ .

Comment: In the Xaml file i can set the attribute of Url as "https://website.com" ??

Comment: last question ..also the cookies of the site will append ???

Comment: It up to different website policy .

Comment: hi again its not working bro i dont know why it says 
The type or namespace name 'CustomRendererAndroid' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: (12, 42):  The type or namespace name 'WebViewRender' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: (18, 33):  'CustomRendererAndroid.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView>)': no suitable method found to override

  (14, 57):  'WebViewRender' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

  (22, 16):  The name 'Control' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You need to put them in specific platform

Comment: I will upload a sample next monday

Comment: yes i do it so but in custom render of Android has many error

Answer (score 0):

I added `Control.LoadUrl(((MyWebView)Element).Url);` line in Android custom renderer otherwise url isn't displayed. Also OnElementPropertyChanged `if(e.property==url)` is never true I moved this block to OnElementChanged method in iOS renderer.